# Nuxt.js регионы как префикс для location.pathname

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Я планирую проект по Nuxt.js, но на данный момент я не могу найти элегантное решение для функциональности регионов. Я был бы очень благодарен за идею, которая поможет реализовать функционал, в котором префикс выбранного региона будет добавлен к URL-адресам.пример:

---

https://example.net/.../ - стандартный регион (EU регион)

---

https://example.net/eu/.../ - EU регион

---

https://example.net/au/.../ - AU регион

---

Нечто подобное делает nuxt/i18n, но проблема в том, что каждый регион может иметь несколько языков и планирую i18n держать только в cookies. На данный момент есть только одна идея - сделать это через NGINX, но я пока не уверен, что это сработает (взять каждый url с префиксом региона и проксировать его на localhost:3000 в качестве примера). Я не прошу вас писать код , мне нужен совет, в какую сторону смотреть (реализовывать через хуки роутера или возможно есть специальный модуль для такого). Если у вас есть какие-то идеи, я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вы как то решили свой вопрос ?

Comment: @PatrickAlias На текущий момент еще не дошел до данной задачи, но есть несколько вариантов которые буду рассматривать: 1.) Нашел в nuxt-i18n код отвечающий за реализацию расширения роутера который добавляет к url локаль из конфига ко всем маршрутам проекта в момент билда (в планах сделать подобный модуль, но только для сторов). 2.) В канале Nuxt.js дали инфу что можно создать в корне pages/_eu.vue в которой делаем middlware, и по идее https://example.net/eu/any-page/  будет смотреть на файл pages/any-page.vue (но нужно проверять)